# Problems after migrating drives to HBA-connected disk shelf

Tags: mount, fdisk, gdisk

I had 4 drives (2x3TB, 1x4TB, 1x18TB) in USB SATA docks connected to my proliant server. I finally got my HBA to recognize my IBM disk array, and managed to get the drives recognized in Ubuntu server 22.04. Problem is, I'm now having filesystem errors when I try to mount the drives. They all have data on them, and I'd rather not lose it. I've got the entirety of my coding history over the last 4 years on these drives, as well as all of my music production (stems, original Cubase project files, etc.) and my family photos.

I've tried `gdisk /dev/sdb` and then `x` and then `v` and `e` for the experts menu, but to no avail. Below is the `-v` output. Any ideas to get these partition tables corrected and remount the drives?

```
root@ganymede:/home/ubuntu# gdisk /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8
Warning! Disk size is smaller than the main header indicates! Loading
secondary header from the last sector of the disk! You should use 'v' to
verify disk integrity, and perhaps options on the experts' menu to repair
the disk.
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.
Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: OK
Backup header: ERROR
Main partition table: OK
Backup partition table: ERROR
Partition table scan:
MBR: protective
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: damaged
****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
Command (? for help):
```

```
Command (? for help): v
Caution: The CRC for the backup partition table is invalid. This table may
be corrupt. This program will automatically create a new backup partition
table when you save your partitions.
Problem: The secondary header's self-pointer indicates that it doesn't reside
at the end of the disk. If you've added a disk to a RAID array, use the 'e'
option on the experts' menu to adjust the secondary header's and partition
table's locations.
Problem: Disk is too small to hold all the data!
Disk size is 5860467632 sectors, needs to be 5860533168 sectors.)
The 'e' option on the experts' menu may fix this problem.
Warning: There is a gap between the main partition table (ending sector 33)
and the first usable sector (65535). This is helpful in some exotic configurations,
but is unusual. The util-linux fdisk program often creates disks like this.
Using 'j' on the experts' menu can adjust this gap.
Problem: GPT claims the disk is larger than it is! (Claimed last usable
sector is 5860533134, but backup header is at
5860533167 and disk size is 5860467632 sectors.
The 'e' option on the experts' menu will probably fix this problem
Problem: partition 1 is too big for the disk.
Caution: Partition 1 doesn't begin on a 8-sector boundary. This may
result in degraded performance on some modern (2009 and later) hard disks.
Consult http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/
for information on disk alignment.
Identified 5 problems!
Command (? for help):
```

Trying the listed suggestions (using `e` in the experts menu and then using `j` in the experts menu) results in the following errors:

```
Command (? for help): x

Expert command (? for help): e
Relocating backup data structures to the end of the disk

Expert command (? for help): j
Currently, main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
Enter new starting location (2 to 65503; default is 2; 1 to abort): 2

Expert command (? for help): w

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by 131037 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Problem: partition 1 is too big for the disk.
Aborting write operation!
Aborting write of new partition table.

Expert command (? for help):
```

Comment: Were these self-contained branded USB drives or standalone drives just plugged into a generic USB to SATA dock?  If the former, then many name brand USB drives have weird partition tables that only work in the USB device they came with (there are ways to make most of these things work with a normal SATA controller but they always, AFAIK, require erasing and reformatting the disk).    BTW, **don't write anything** to this kind of disk when plugged into a normal PC SATA port, and don't re-partition it - then they won't work in their original USB devices either.

Comment: These are standard SATA drives that were plugged into a randomly branded $25 USB dock I got on amazon. Out of curiosity, I took a disk out of the storage shelf and put it back in the USB dock and it works perfectly. I have a pair of 10TB drives coming in this week, I'll have to move all my data off using the USB docks and reformat once they're back in the storage shelf again.